# How to do subpages in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

So, I've been looking all day for this, but I can't find anything about it. Suppose, I have a webapp with a settings page `www.example.com/settings`. What do I do if I want to add subpages to this settings pages, e.g. `www.example.com/settings/account`. Below you can find my current implementation, but that isn't working...

```
var Example = angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

Example.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    // route for account settings
    .when('/settings/account', {
        templateUrl : 'views/settings/account.php',
        controller  : 'SettingsController'
    })

    // route for profile settings
    .when('/settings/profile', {
        templateUrl : 'views/settings/profile.php',
        controller  : 'SettingsController'
    })

    // route for the settings
    .when('/settings', {
        templateUrl : 'views/settings.php',
        controller  : 'SettingsController'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And this is an example of the `settings/account` view:

```
<div ng-controller="SettingsController">

    <h1>ExampleApp</h1>
    <h4>Account | Settings</h4>

</div>
```

**======================================**

I added the code suggested to `main.js`, but now it keeps going to `/home`

```
Example.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   //
   // For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
   //
   // Now set up the states
   $stateProvider
     .state('home', {
       url: "/home",
       templateUrl: "views/home.html"
     })
     .state('add', {
       url: "/add",
       templateUrl: "views/add.html"
     })
     .state('edit', {
       url: "/edit",
       templateUrl: "views/edit.html"
     })
     .state('settings', {
       url: "/settings",
       templateUrl: "views/settings.html"
     })
     .state('account', {
       url: "/settings/account",
       templateUrl: "views/settings/account.html"
     });
 });
```

Comment: don't declare controllers twice.  What isn't working? What errors are thrown?

Comment: Did your other pages are routing properly, except settings/account..?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed since posting this question. The page keeps loading, throwing errors until it eventually crashes the Chrome tab. The errors that are thrown are coming from `ContentVeil.js` and `mtgm.js`.

Comment: Yes, all others are working properly.

Comment: Why the .php extension on your templates?

Comment: So, I can use php in them...

Comment: @ User183849481 - Seems as if the application is mixing server side logic and client side logic in the same application. Generally when using Angular, the intention is to use the framework exclusively on the client side for logic, rendering views and navigating url paths. The only real need for the use of PHP would to deliver data to the Angular controllers as needed to render the different views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `ui-router`. It's a 3rd-party module. It supports everything the normal ngRoute can do as well as many extra functions.

Ui-router would be very helpful in your example using `states`. [states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateproviderstatestatename-stateconfig) allow you to map and access different information about different states and you can easily pass information between states via [$statsParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service).

LIVE DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/37O7NFnrKYsgwbF5eqRt

## First you need to create the different views:

### Index view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
    <title>exampleApp</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="container">
  <p><i>Best viewed in pop-out mode to see location changes. Click blue button on the right.</i></p>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="#">exampleApp</a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="settings">settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="well" ui-view></div>        
    </div>
  </div>         

  <!-- Angular -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
  <!-- UI-Router -->
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

  <!-- App Script -->
  <script>
    var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ["ui.router"])
    exampleApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
      .state('index', {
        url: "/index",
      })
      .state('settings', {
        url: "/settings",
        templateUrl: "settings.html"
      })
      .state('settings.account', {
        url: "/account",
        templateUrl: "settings.account.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.account = "i'm the account view"
        }
      })
      .state('settings.profile', {
        url: "/profile",
        templateUrl: "settings.profile.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.profile = "i'm the profile view"
        }
      })
      .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "home.html"
      });
  });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

### Home view

```
<h1>I'm the home view</h1>
```

### Settings view

```
<h1>Settings view</h1>
<hr/>
<p><a ui-sref=".account">Account</a></p>
<p><a ui-sref=".profile">Profile</a></p>
<div ui-view></div>
```

### Account view

```
<h3>Account view</h3>
<ul>
  {{account}}
</ul>
```

### Profile view

```
<h3>Profile View</h3>
<ul>
  {{profile}}
</ul>
```

## And then you configure the state in the module config:

I directly add the module config in the index.

Comment: Okay, so I added your code to my `main.js`, but now it keeps going to `/home`. No matter what I visit...

Comment: I guess you forgot about adding the `<!-- UI-Router -->` using 
    `<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>`

I updated the home.html with these changes.

Comment: I did that before, but what happens is that subroutes aren't working now...they just display a blank page.

Comment: Ok I just created a Plunker with a working project. Let me know what you think. http://plnkr.co/edit/37O7NFnrKYsgwbF5eqRt

Comment: What happens is that if I go to `/settings`, everything works just fine. But if I go to `/settings/account` directly, I get a blank page....

Comment: it works on Plunker, the issue you are having is because of your local configuration somewhere in your files, in the state probably. 

Please copy and past everything from plunker, test it and start from there. It would be easier to find out the reason of the problem then.  

If you can't figure it out I am more than happy to help you out over a screen sharing.